# How to get correct bounding box when camera is at an angle

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, object-detection, google-coral

I am new to machine learning and currently I am using the Google Coral USB accelerator and Rapsberry Pi to perform object detection. When I point the Raspberry Pi camera to image right in front, the object is detected and bounding box is drawn correctly as shown below.

[image: Correct bounding box]

However, when the camera is at an angle, the bounding box is completely wrong as below:

[image: Incorrect bounding box]

How do I figure out the correct bounding box coordinates for the object when the camera is at an angle?

Comment: what do you mean 'the camera is at an angle' ? did you input below image in to the model as it is? or input other image and transform angle?

Comment: Did you have images of the object from different angles for the training, also try to use the argumentation of image in the input stream for training.

Comment: For inference, I displayed the test image on a monitor and placed the camera at different locations relative to the monitor - right opposite to monitor, side (45deg) of the monitor. So by 'angle', I meant the view angle. I did include objects from different view angles in training.

Comment: What program did you run (to create the images with the bounding boxes)? What model did you use? Can you provide the input images? If you describe exactly how to reproduce it and provide the required resources (i.e. program, model, input images), it is easier to help.

Comment: So far I can only guess that your used model has not been trained properly for your object type. Maybe the training data only contained images of parking signs seen from the front. I get correct results (most of the time) for `person`s shown from a different angle using the model MobileNet SSD v2 (COCO), see https://github.com/google-coral/edgetpu/raw/master/test_data/mobilenet_ssd_v2_coco_quant_postprocess_edgetpu.tflite